When google translate plugin applied Getting Uncaught DOMException:Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node':node to be removed not child of this node
After applying google translate and redirect to other component in the page throwing this error : Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node

in react and node js application

I couldn't get any proper solution for this error
